# how to make ground-truth or training classes for hyperspectral image classification

Tags: python-3.x

I have a hyperspectral image having 186 bands. What is appropriate way to generate ground truths so that I can use it to make training class to train a machine learning model. The image is as below:[image]

Answer (score 0):

We need to manually create masks or assign classes to regions of interest on any 2D image serving as the ground truth data (may need to convert it into the same type as the hyperspectral image data, containing only a single band information)